# API request to Stripe fails (Error: Not a valid URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I want to build a simple checkout page using the Stripe Prebuilt Checkout Page in a Node application.

I follow all the necessary steps in the Stripe docs but the API request doesn't seem to work.

server.js -

```
const express = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "<mySecretKey>"
);

const app = express();

app.get("/checkout-sucess", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Success</h1>");
});

app.get("/checkout-cancel", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Cancelled</h1>");
});

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          product_data: {
            name: "Cewa",
          },
          unit_amount: 200,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "/checkout-success",
    cancel_url: "/checkout-cancel",
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
});

app.listen(4242, () => {
  console.log("Server is live on Port 4242!");
});
```

checkout.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stripe API Test</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button
      type="button"
      id="checkout-button"
      style="
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: beige;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
      "
    >
      Checkout
    </button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe(
      "<myPublishableAPIKey"
    );
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

When I make this request, I get the following error in the console coming from `checkout.html` -

**Error: Not a valid URL**

I don't think I've missed anything from the docs. Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add real success and cancel url, please check below code:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          product_data: {
            name: "Cewa",
          },
          unit_amount: 200,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://sitename.com/checkout-success",
    cancel_url: "http://sitename.com/checkout-cancel",
  });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Should the success_url be post or get?

Comment: Both success_url and cancel_url is GET request.

Comment: Strange, but it stopped working for me. I had specified localhost:8000 which was working fine, but now even https://your-site.com/checkout-success does not work. I get "Not a Valid Url". Is there anything necessary to be enabled from stripe dashboard?

Answer (score 6):

The `success_url` and `cancel_url` fields need to be a real URL accessible on the internet. `/checkout-success` won't work, you have to pass in the full URL e.g. `https://your-site.com/checkout-success`.

Comment: how to test in localhost

Comment: `localhost` will work fine, as long as you provide the full URL. E.g. `success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success`